# Setup basic proxypass in Apache

Tags: apache, configuration

I have a web application that communicates to a web service deployed on the same server. The web app was written with Tibco General Interface and works well only when it is running locally on the development system. When I deploy the web app to the Apache server it fails with code 200 apparently due to cross domain data. I use Firefox as a browser. I have tried changing Internet Explorer to access cross domain data and it works however IE is not an option.

Web application runs on `192.168.2.205` (port 80).
Web service runs on `192.168.2.205:8040`

I have tried a number of things with proxypass inside Apache with no luck.

Comment: Will help if you tell us how you have tried to make a proxypass... At the moment the questions would seem a little nonconstructive... so pass your code.

Comment: The web service endpoint URL is http://192.168.2.205:8040/services/HAservice is  I tried ProxyPass /HAservice http://192.168.2.205:8040/services/HAservice and point the web app to the URL http://192.168.2.205/HAservice. This was totally random attempt...

Comment: I haven't been in the exact same position as you, but it was quite similar. I did a write-up of it here: http://deliciouslyweird.com/2012/06/apache-virtualhost-mod_proxy/. Like I said it's not identical so I won't put it as an answer, but perhaps it'll push you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an apache virtual host configuration that should work for you to reverse proxy your web app through Apache.  Replace `mydomain.example.com` with your actual domain name.  You will need to have `mod_poxy` and `mod_proxy_http` loaded by apache and if you use `ProxyHTML` directives, you will need `mod_proxy_html` as well.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName mydomain.example.com

    # Enable a reverse proxy to your web app
    ProxyRequests Off        
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.2.205:8040/

    # If your web app is setting cookies for the wrong domain name.
    # This fixes when they are set for 'localhost'.
    # If your web application is setting cookies correctly,
    # leave this section out
    ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain localhost mydomain.example.com

    # If your web app is writing links incorrectly.
    # If the web app sets all the URLs correctly,
    # leave this section out
    ProxyHTMLEnable On
    ProxyHTMLURLMap http://localhost/ http://mydomain.example.com/
    ProxyHTMLURLMap http://192.168.2.205/ http://mydomain.example.com/
    ProxyHTMLURLMap http://192.168.2.205:8040/ http://mydomain.example.com/

</VirtualHost>
```